# Umbraco 7 Custom Property Editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco 7.4 and I've created a custom google map property editor which has the autocomplete feature enabled on the map.

I've created a separate standard textbox property below the google map property on my document type, and when the user selects an autosuggestion from google's autocomplete feature, I have it updating the value of the standard textbox property but when I save & publish the node, the value isn't actually stored with the textbox.  It's odd because if I manually write in text to the textbox and publish, it stores the data just fine.  I'm a jQuery developer by nature so I was kind of surprised to see that the syntax worked inside of the Angular controller...any help would be much appreciated!

**The event listener where I'm updating the textbox value (last line)**

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
                infowindow.close();
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    return;
                }
                var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());
                    map.setCenter(coords);

                // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
                marker.setPlace({
                    placeId: place.place_id,
                    location: coords
                });
                marker.setVisible(true);

                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                    'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                    place.formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                codeLatLng(coords, geocoder);
                $('#googlePlaceID').val(place.place_id).text(place.place_id);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a kind-of hacky solution to guide Angular into seeing that text was written on the other textbox property editor but it works.  I replaced the last line in the original codeblock with:

```
        $('#googlePlaceID').select().focus().val(place.place_id);
        var e = document.getElementById('googlePlaceID');
        var $e = angular.element(e);
        $e.triggerHandler('input');
```